# While Binding static library in xamarin below error is geting

Tags: c#, xamarin, static-libraries, objective-sharpie

I have run following command

**sharpie bind -output xyz -namespace xyz -sdk iphoneos10.3 /Users/maheshwari/Projects/xyz/xyz/redparkSerial.h**

**Output:**

> Automated binding is complete, but there are a few APIs which have
>   been flagged with [Verify] attributes. While the entire binding should
>   be audited for   best API design practices, look more closely at APIs
>   with the following Verify attribute hints:
>
> MethodToProperty (9 instances):
>       An Objective-C method was bound as a C# property due to convention such as taking no parameters and returning a value (non-void return).
>   Often methods
>       like these should be bound as properties to surface a nicer API, but sometimes false-positives can occur and the binding should
>   actually be a method.
>
> InferredFromMemberPrefix (5 instances):
>       The name of this originally anonymous declaration was taken from a common prefix of its members.
>
> Once you have verified a Verify attribute, you should remove it from
>   the binding source code. The presence of Verify attributes
>   intentionally cause   build failures.
>        For more information about the Verify attribute hints above, consult the Objective Sharpie documentation by running 'sharpie docs'
>   or visiting the   following URL:
>
> ```
> http://xmn.io/sharpie-docs
> ```

Comment: Guys, please suggest me what should i do. Is there any example is available?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your output path. There should be an ApiDefinition.cs and a Structs.cs Add those two files to your Xamarin.iOS Binding Project and check the mentioned MethodToProperty, InferredFromMemberPrefix instances as well as everything with a [Verify]-attribute.

See https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/ for more infos and a walkthrough.